# Not getting correct output when using command line argument in java

Tags: java, math.sqrt

```
//Square root of a no. using command line argument
class Calculator {
    double i;
    double x = Math.sqrt(i);
}

class SquareRoot {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Calculator a = new Calculator();
        a.i = Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);
        System.out.println("The square root of " + a.i + " is " + a.x);
    }
}
```

My Output:

```
The square root of 64 is 0.0
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Because `double x=Math.sqrt(i);` is calculated before `a.i=Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);` (and it is `0`).

Comment: So to correct it i need to first make a method and then call it .Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
class Calculator {
    double i, x;
    void squareRoot() {
        x = Math.sqrt(i);
    }
}

class SquareRoot {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Calculator a = new Calculator();
        a.i = Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);
        a.squareRoot();
        System.out.println("The square root of " + a.i + " is " + a.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: So without using squareRoot() method i can't do it directly?Can you explain it further?

Comment: in your code `Math.sqrt(i)` execute before getting a value of variable a. your x's value is set when you are creating object of `calculator` class. which is executed before getting value of a.that's why you need to call squareroot function after getting value of i.